# Write and recode from one csv file to another

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to select specific columns from a large tab-delimited CSV file and output only certain columns to a new CSV file. Furthermore, I want to recode the data as this happens. If the cell has a value of 0 then just output 0. However, if the cell has a value of greater than 0, then just output 1 (i.e., all values greater than 0 are coded as 1).

Here's what I have so far:

```
import csv

outputFile = open('output.csv', 'wb')
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)
included_cols = range(9,2844)

with open('source.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        content = list(row[i] for i in included_cols)
        outputWriter.writerow(content)
```

The first issue I am having is that I want to also take from column 6. I wasn't sure how to write column 6 and then columns 9-2844.

Second, I wasn't sure how to do the recoding on the fly as I write the new CSV.

Answer (score 0):

> I wasn't sure how to write column 6 and then columns 9-2844.

```
included_cols = [6] + list(range(9,2844))
```

This works because [you can add two lists together](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations). Note that in Python3, [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) doesn't return a list, so we have to coerce it.

> I wasn't sure how to do the recoding on the fly

```
content = list((1 if row[i] > 0 else 0) for i in included_cols)
```

This works because of the [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions): `1 if row[i] > 0 else 0`. The general form `A if cond else B` evaluates to either `A` or `B`, depending upon the condition.

Another form, which I think is ["too clever by half"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=too+smart+by+half) is `content = list((row[i] and 1) for i in included_cols)`. This works because the [`and` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) always returns one or the other of its inputs.

Comment: As with the answer above, that seems to recode the entire row to a '1'. I was looking to recode just the single cell to a '1'.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `included_cols = [5] + range(8, 2844)` since the first column is at index 0 in the list?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import csv

outputFile = open('output.csv', 'wb')
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)
included_cols = [5] + range(8,2844) # you can just merge two lists

with open('source.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    outputWriter.writerow(reader[0]) # write header row unchanged
    for row in reader[1:]: # skip header row
        content = [int(row[i]) if i == 5 else (0 if int(row[i]) == 0 else 1) for i in included_cols]
        outputWriter.writerow(content)
```

Comment: As with the other code, that seems to recode the entire row to a '1'. I was looking to recode just the single cell to a '1'.

Comment: Are items in row already converted to integers or are they just strings representing a number? In case they are strings I added conversion to int. Without the conversion comparison of string with 0 will always evaluate to false.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `included_cols = [5] + range(8, 2844)` since the first column is at index 0 in the list?

Comment: @user2676699 yes you are correct. 

That seems to have worked, but I had to remove the header otherwise it would try to test that as well. How do I write the header first but skip it for the testing? Also, I realized that I just want to write column 5 without trying to transform it. How can I do that?

Comment: @matt  read and write the header outside the loop.  If that doesn't make sense, ask a new question about that and I can answer that with some code I just wrote that does the same thing

Comment: That's very close, but you aren't able to specify rows like that in the csv module. I can skip the first row using next(reader) and I can even print the first row out in the same way (print next(reader)), but I'm having trouble getting it to print out the specific headings I'm interested in. The same "list(row[i] for i in included_cols)" isn't working in this case.